# Expected number of packed items in box

Tags: pr.probability

Assume we have a box of size $n$, some items $X_i, i \in N$ of unknown distribution, with expected size $\mu>0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. We want to randomly and greedily pack the box with the items until one item does not fit anymore. Let $I$ denote the number of packed items.

I would like to show that, for a function $f(n)$ where $\omega (1) << f(n) << \sqrt{n}$, this holds:

$P[\frac{n}{\mu}(1-\frac{1}{f(n)})\leq I \leq \frac{n}{\mu}(1+\frac{1}{f(n)})] = 1- \mathcal{O}(\frac{f(n)^2}{n})$

I've tried using Chebyshev's inequality on the complementary probability ($I$ outside of the interval) to bound the probability. But this requires knowledge of the variance of $I$ which I am having problems figuring out.

Comment: I is a "first passage time" for a biased random walk. That term might help you with finding a useful reference.

Comment: Thanks Yoav, will look into that. But won't that require some knowledge about the distribution of $X_i$?

Comment: If the X_i hands you the items, I don't see what choice you have where greedily applies, unless you can choose to stop before the box is full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $S_i$ is the sum of the first $i$ items chosen (I assume this is with replacement), then $S_i$ has mean $\mu i$ and variance $\sigma^2 i$.
Now $a(n) \le I < b(n)$ iff $S_{a(n)} \le n$ and $S_{b(n)} > n$.
Use Chebyshev on those.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please explain in little more detail how I would apply Chebyshev on the intersection of the two events $S_{a(n)} \leq n$ and $S_{b(n)} > n$. Are they independent events?

Comment: No, they're certainly not independent, but you can use $P(A \cap B) \ge 1 - P(A^c) - P(B^c)$.